# Get result from multiple where conditional statements in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get the result based upon the values of variables `temp_DestinationGroupName`, `temp_CountryName` and `temp_RateTypeId`.

If any of these variables are null or 0, it should not be included in where clause and rest statements should work and bring the result. I am getting zero rows using this query. Kindly suggest me something with these conditions in where clause. i tried following solutions on stackoverflow but still not getting the desired result.

```
var Rows = _CustomerRatesList.Where(w => (w.Id != rates.Id)
 && (w.DestinationGroupName == temp_DestinationGroupName || temp_DestinationGroupName!= null)
 && (w.CountryName == temp_CountryName || temp_CountryName!=null)
 && (w.RateTypeId == temp_RateTypeId || temp_RateTypeId !=0));
```

Comment: Are these queries against a database? If so, please expand your question, i.e. which ORM you use etc. The translation of expression trees into SQL by the LINQ provider is massively implementation-specific. Right now your code is apparently translated into inner joins. You may want to try to put the null checks in front.

Comment: Please give us an example. each of the && condition check executes only if previous ones return true.

Comment: no i have this query in c#(Visual Studio). and _CustomerRatesList is a list containing these values.

Comment: `var Rows = _CustomerRatesList.Except(w => (w.DestinationGroupName == temp_DestinationGroupName || temp_DestinationGroupName!= null)
 && (w.CountryName == temp_CountryName || temp_CountryName!=null) && (w.RateTypeId == temp_RateTypeId || temp_RateTypeId !=0)).Where(w =>  w.Id != rates.Id);`

Comment: if i change && into || i am getting all the records of list excluding the Id check, its working, but null values check is not working

Answer (score 2):

```
(w.DestinationGroupName == temp_DestinationGroupName || temp_DestinationGroupName!= null)
```

Your condition here will return true as long as your input variable `temp_DestinationGroupName` is not null. I don't think that's what you had in mind.

Comment: If this condition is true and others are false, only this should bring the result, but i am getting all the rows

Comment: You have the same issue in all of your conditions.

Comment: Yes same issue in all these conditions

Comment: ...so you're never filtering out any results, so you're getting all the rows

Comment: No em not getting any record since i used && and if i change this to ||, whole list is showing, no filtering

Answer (score 1):

You can split in many `Where` to make your request more readable :

```
var Rows = _CustomerRatesList.Where(w => w.Id != rates.Id)
                             .Where(w => w.DestinationGroupName != temp_DestinationGroupName || temp_DestinationGroupName != null)
                             .Where(w => w.CountryName != temp_CountryName || temp_CountryName != null)
                             .Where(w => w.RateTypeId != temp_RateTypeId || temp_RateTypeId !=0);
```

Notice that you must use `!=` in first conditioon of all `Where`, so you'll get all data except when it's null. In your logic, may be the conditions will be `==` :

```
var Rows = _CustomerRatesList.Where(w => w.Id != rates.Id)
                             .Where(w => w.DestinationGroupName == temp_DestinationGroupName || temp_DestinationGroupName == null)
                             .Where(w => w.CountryName == temp_CountryName || temp_CountryName == null)
                             .Where(w => w.RateTypeId == temp_RateTypeId || temp_RateTypeId ==0);
```

Each `Where` result is an `IEnumerable`, Rows will be a `IEnumerable`. If you want a `List`, just add `.ToList()`

Comment: Thank you, i wrote my where conditions in separate lines, perfect !

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to this problem, now i am getting filtered result.
Thank you all for your time :)

```
var otherRows = _CustomerRatesList.Where(w => w.Id != rates.Id)
                         .Where(w => w.DestinationGroupName == temp_DestinationGroupName || temp_DestinationGroupName == null)
                         .Where(w => w.CountryName == temp_CountryName || temp_CountryName == null)
                         .Where(w => w.RateTypeId == temp_RateTypeId || temp_RateTypeId == 0);
```